# Custom CSS class for region in DS not working as intended

Tags: theming

I've successfully created a custom layout in ds (display suite), assigning various fields (simple, code, image) to each of the regions in there.

I've also managed to successfully create custom css classes for the fields and assigning these accordingly via the corresponding ds menu/ui.

Now I'm trying to achieve the very same for one of the regions, but so far I'm failing badly at this. What I'm intending to configure would be a region (width 100%) containing an image which might have a width of less than 100%. So all the remaining space in that region, surrounding the image, is supposed to be set to a particular colour.

(A) My custom ds layout

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| region #01                                                           |
|                                                                      |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+

+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| region #02                                                           |
|                                                                      |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+

+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|:region #03::::::::::::::::::::::###################################::|
|:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::### image #01 #####################::|
|:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::###################################::|
|:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::###################################::|
|:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::###################################::|
|:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::###################################::|
|:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::###################################::|
|:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::###################################::|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+

+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| region #04                                                           |
|                                                                      |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Note:

- ':' would be the [background] colour I'd like to display.

**That's how expect the node getting rendered!**

(B) In my custom.css the following classes for that region are being defined:

```
.region-picture {
  float: right;
  max-height: 30%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.region-background {
  background-color: #b3b3b3;
  background: #b3b3b3;
  color: #b3b3b3;
}
```

Note

custom css class 'region-background' assigned to 'region #03' via 'Manage display'/'Custom classes';

just as outlined at https://www.drupal.org/node/2059481.

(C)Instead of the node getting rendered as shown above, it's being rendered as shown below:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| region #01                                                           |
|                                                                      |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+

+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| region #02                                                           |
|                                                                      |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+

+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| region #03                      ###################################  |
|                                 ### image #01 #####################  |
|                                 ###################################  |
|                                 ###################################  |
|                                 ###################################  |
|                                 ###################################  |
|                                 ###################################  |
|                                 ###################################  |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+

+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| region #04                                                           |
|                                                                      |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**So region #3 (here in (C))is rendered differently than intended (as in (A))!**

(D) Pulling up the browser's inspector reveals

```
div class="ds-region-03 region-background"
  div class="group-picture field-group-div"
    div class="field field-name-field-picture field-type-image field-label-hidden region-picture"
      div class="field-items"
        div class="field-item even"
          img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://myhost.local/?q=system/files/image.png" width="539" height="198" alt=""
        /div
      /div
    /div
  /div
/div
```

So my custom css class for the region is there, but--being a noob in terms of drupal and css--I've got not the faintest ideas as why it's getting rendered differently. :(

(E) Latest discovery

Without assigning a custom css class to the picture (image #01) displayed in region #03 the (background) colour to the region is set as intended.

As soon as I'm assigning a custom css class (see below) to the field (picture) contained within that region, the (background) colour is either removed or simply ignored.

```
.region-picture {
  float: right;
}
```

--Sil68

Comment: Hi and welcome to Drupal Answers. This question appears off-topic as it is about CSS and not Drupal-related. [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) appears to be a more valid place for your question. Please also take a look at [this Help Centre article](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: As for my question, I reckon it's predominantly drupal-centric, as it'a about how to get this working in/with drupal. The css on its own, outside drupal is working perfectly fine.

Comment: I'm sorry, your question is not clear to me. So the rendered HTML is different than what you expect? Could you please edit your question and say what was the expected HTML? Or which precisely is the problem?

Comment: Just added a some remarks (bold typeface). Basically (A) is what I want to achieve, (C) is what I've got.